# RJMP OPcode Help, Avr assembler

Tags: assembly, avr, opcode

I have a question for solving the value of K in the opcode for rjmp. The opcode is 1100 kkkk kkkk kkkk. Where Pc<- PC +k + 1. When I solve for this I get k = -1 and then i know the 12 bits for K in the opcode is 0xFFF. I then assumed my answer is CFFF, but it is is incorrect. The answer is CFFD. What am I doing incorrectly? Heres the code I was given.

```
foo: NOP
  NOP
  RJMP foo
```

Comment: _"I then assumed my answer is CFFF"_. Why? Your question contains no information about the addresses of `foo` and the `RJMP` instruction.

Comment: i left out it began at memory location 0

Comment: @Michael i found out how to reply

Answer (score 1):

You want to jump back 1 word, and the formula gives `k + 1 = -1` so `k = -2` which is`0xFFE` on 12 bits. Plugging in the opcode gives `0xCFFE`. You can check by using an assembler:

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   00 00           nop
   2:   fe cf           rjmp    .-4             ; 0x0 <foo>
```

Other way to look at it is that the offset is measured from the next instruction, because the cpu already incremented PC when the offset is added. That's where the +1 comes from.

Comment: could you explain why it is 1 word and how that changes the formula for k, say if it was 2 words distance?

Comment: It's 1 word because it's the previous instruction and each instruction is 1 word. Of course the formula doesn't change for 2 words either. Then you'd have `k + 1 = -2` so `k = -3`. Other way to look at it is that the offset is measured from the next instruction, because the cpu already incremented PC when the offset is added. That's where the `+1` comes from.

Comment: so if there were 3 nop instead of two it would be k+1 = -3, k = -4?

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me for my mid term